# osm2po errors when converting pbf file

Tags: openstreetmap, osm2po

I am trying to prepare OpenStreetMap data for routing.  I have downloaded version 4.8.8 of *osm2po*.  I also downloaded `north-america-latest.osm.pbf` from Geofabrik.  The command I am running is:

```sh
$ java -Xmx16g -jar osm2po-core-4.8.8-signed.jar \
  cmd=tjsg tileSize=x "C:\maps\north-america-latest.osm.pbf"
```

The process seems to get well on its way, but I keep encountering a fatal error:

```java
FATAL  Exception at Thu May 01 15:16:58 CDT 2014
       Message: java.io.FileNotFoundException: osm\tw_raw.2po 
         (The system cannot find the file specified)
       Class: java.lang.RuntimeException
       Stacktrace:
       de.cm.osm2po.primitives.InStreamDisk.<init>(InStreamDisk.java:30)
       de.cm.osm2po.converter.Joiner.run(Joiner.java:206)
       de.cm.osm2po.Main.runJoiner(Main.java:196)
       de.cm.osm2po.Main.main(Main.java:131)
```

I am not sure if there is a problem with the command as I have executed it, or if there may be a data problem, or what? - I am using Java version 1.7.0_55.

Please let me know if there is any other information which would be helpful in getting to the bottom of this.

Comment: Is the message itself correct? I mean, does the file actually not exist?

Comment: You may also send the log file to my info@-addi.

Comment: That is correct, that the file tw_raw.2po does not exist.

Comment: Not sure. The website says that it will create an OSM dir at the current workdir to save temp files. http://osm2po.de  Nobody knows if just the path is wrong or a files is missed.  
Sorry but usually people use pgrouting together with OSM, so I guess you need to ask the dev for support :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue can be **closed**.
Extract from a corresponding email I received:

*... Upon closer inspection, I see that the pbf file I was using is ~2GB in size.  According to geofabrik, it should be nearer to 6GB in size.  I was using **wget** to download, and I didn't see any errors during that process, so I am confused by this discrepancy...*